# Where can I find out about a MacOS Product Distribution File?

Tags: macos, productbuild

The man page for "productbuild" for Mac OS talks about a distribution file:

> ```
>  --distribution dist-path
>              Use the distribution file at dist-path to define the presentation, choices and packages to
>              be installed by the product. Each of the package names referenced in the given distribution
>              file must be found in a path specified with the --package-path flag.
> ```

But I can't find inforation about what goes in the distribution file anywhere. What sort of stuff goes in there? Is there a reference page for it?

Comment: I too want answer fo this question. Where can we get this file. Or atleast any reference document to write our own Distribution file. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly under-documented, but there is a little bit of information out there:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Introduction.html
- http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/Ivanhoe/FLAT.html

I'd also recommend examining distribution files inside existing packages. You can expand a flat package with:

```
pkgutil --expand Foo.pkg destination_folder
```

Comment: That second link is referencing the old way (packagemaker).

Comment: Yes, it was written before productbuild existed, but the documentation is still valid.